# Change views after inflating from XML

Tags: android, draw, android-inflate

I have made a layout in XML consisting of a LinearLayout having 2 TextViews as its children.

I want to draw a vertical line within the second text view. For that, I created a class and inflated the above XML in its constructor. Now, what methods do I have to override in order to draw the line, and how do I get the `Canvas` for the text view ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Override `onDraw(Canvas canvas)` method of the `TextView` (by creating a custom View that extends `TextView`) to draw the line. A simpler approach is to use `RelativeLayout` and put an `ImageView` with transparent background over the 2nd `TextView` and with the line and set its visibility to visible when you need to draw the line.

Comment: Thank you !! The other method you've given is quite good !!
For overriding onDraw(), how will I specify that I want to draw in the second text view. Im getting only a single Canvas right !!

Comment: Try the update and yes it returns the canvas for this View only.

Comment: The code is not working.
It says insert a semi colon after the findViewBydId() call. Is there some other way to override the onDraw for the text view ?

Comment: You can create your own Custom View that extends TextView and overrides onDraw(), however, let me check why the a/m code is not working.

Comment: Since it is protected, you must Subclass TextView. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Check this [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html)